# pandas read_excel returns columns is wrong order if number of columns are less than total columns in the sheet

Tags: python, pandas

I have an xlsx file which contains 3 columns. This is how my xlsx file looks like:

```
Items   Object          Information
Item1   Some Object     Some Information
Item2   Some Object     Some Information
Item3   Some Object     Some Information
Item4   Some Object     Some Information
```

When reading this using pandas.read_excel, i am getting wrong column orders based on what I pass in `names` argument.

When I say

```
df_sheet = pd.read_excel("myfile.xlsx", 
                         sheet_name="mysheet", 
                         engine="openpyxl", 
                         header=None, 
                         names=list("ABC"))
```

I get Items column as A, Object column as B, and Information column as C.

When I say

```
df_sheet = pd.read_excel("myfile.xlsx", 
                         sheet_name="mysheet", 
                         engine="openpyxl", 
                         header=None, 
                         names=list("AB"))
```

I get Items column as B, and Object column as A.

I was under the impression that pandas will preserve the column order and by passing `names` argument in read_excel, i am asking it to name the first column as A and second column as B but for some reason when I read only 2 columns out of 3 the column order is not right but works fine if I read all 3 columns.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Want to confirm it's `Items` you are getting in column B and not `Information` when running your second code block? When I run the same block I get `Information` in column B instead of `Items`.

Comment: @kevin41: You are right. I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue boils down to the index column. Pandas did preserve the order of columns, it's just that the first column was used for the index.

You can fix this by specifying the columns you want to use with `usecols`:

```
df = pd.read_excel("myfile.xlsx", sheet_name="mysheet", engine="openpyxl", header=None, names=list("AB"), usecols="A:B")
```